# Приведение типов. Вывод в консоль

Tags: javascript

Думала, что абсолютно точно понимаю приведение типов. Но столкнулась с выражением `{} + []`. Именно в таком порядке.

Проблема в том, что при вводе в консоли браузера это выражение выводит 0.

При вводе все в той же консоли браузера выражений вида: `({} + []), ({} + []).toString(), ({} + []).valueOf(), console.log({} + [])`

будет выведено: `[object Object]`

собственно то, что и предполагалось получить.

Вопрос: почему?

Comment: Потому что это `JS`. :)) У него есть свои маленькие косяки которые являются косяками даже для динамически типизированного языка. И поверьте, это далеко не все «Косяки» в `JS` Которые вы встретите за время работы.

Comment: в случае выражения `{} +[]` фигурные скобки считаются не частью выражения, а пустым блоком кода, поэтому приведенное выражение эквивалентно `+[]` -> что вполне себе равняется 0

Comment: @Grundy спасиииииибо! прям от сердца отлегло!